# RabbitMQ - access to vhost 'XXX' refused for user 'guest'

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I am using RabbitMQ 3.0.3 version. The service was working fine for last 4-5 years. Recently some updates patches were installed on the server and the Service stopped responding. This is what is happening:

1. The RabbitMQ service (windows service) is running but not responding.
2. In the log file I see error `access to vhost 'XXX' refused for user 'guest'`
3. The management console is throwing site cannot be reached error

What options do I have here? I cannot update RabbitMQ version as my code starts to fail. I have not tried reinstalling the service.

**I am using RabbitMQ 3.0.3 - How can I request `guest` account to be accessible even from remote machine. `rabbitmq.conf` file only appeared after version 3.7.0**

Comment: Do you know if you rely on RabbitMQ to store your queue and consumer config? Or could the app recreate that in a blank MQ? The error suggests that the guest account isn't allowed into your porn vhost, or perhaps that it doesn't exist.

Comment: I've got this before when the vhost didn't exist.

Comment: Sounds like your vhost either doesn't exist, or the user guest doesn't have access to it. Usually guest is limited to localhost only by RMQ. Use a real user acct.

Comment: @Davesoft: App creates the queue. Like i said, this setup was working for very long time and its not been touched. The issue appeared on two machines. Even if the guest account is blocked or got deleted on this machine, the management console should continue to work. How can i recreate the user account?

Comment: @KevinSmith How can I create the Vhost? How did you resolved this issue?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson : How can I create vhost? I am also not able to launch management console

Comment: Read the docs: https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I am using RabbitMQ 3.0.3 - How can i request `guest` account to be accessible even from remote machine. `rabbitmq.conf` file only appeared after version 3.7.0

Comment: @Davesoft   I am using RabbitMQ 3.0.3 - How can i request `guest` account to be accessible even from remote machine. `rabbitmq.conf` file only appeared after version 3.7.0

Comment: Why use guest? Make a real account :)

Comment: @Davesoft: That is how my app was configured. Obviously creating a user id and using it is not a big change but i was wondering why the guest account is suddenly being disabled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not saying this is the right answer but this is what I did to fix this issue.

**Confusing part:** RabbitMQ says `Guest` account is not allowed to access RabbitMQ from a remote machine. I am using RabbitMQ 3.0.3 and I am able to access RabbitMQ from remote machine using `Guest` account. I am not sure if they made this change in a later version.

**Fix I applied:**

1. Opened RabbitMQ management console.
2. Clicked on Virtual Host
3. Created the Virtual host (gave a name and clicked on Add Virtual host button). `The name of Virtual host was same as the one I saw in error message "access to vhost 'XXX' refused for user 'guest'"`
4. Gave permission to that virtual host to guest account.

Comment: This is correct. In a future release, `guest` was limited to `localhost`-only connections. Please see the `loopback_users` setting in the RabbitMQ documentation.